# Проблема в запросе к БД (SQLite)

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, django-orm, django-filter

И так...
Имееем:

```
lvl1 = lavel.objects.all().filter(lvl=3)
lvl2 = lavel.objects.all().filter(lvl=4)
lvl3 = lavel.objects.all().filter(lvl=5)

context = {
        'Level1': lvl1,
        'Level2': lvl2,
        'Level3': lvl3,
}

return render(request, "blog/index.html", context=context)
```

В самом шаблоне:

```
{% for lvl1 in Level1 %}
        # ...

    {% for lvl2 in Level2.filter(owner=lvl1.owner) %}
        # ...

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Ошибка:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(owner=lvl1.owner)' from 'Level2.filter(owner=lvl1.owner)'
```

Если это нужно, вот сама структура БД:

```
class lavel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lvl = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0, verbose_name='Уровень')
    alias = models.TextField(null=True, default='', verbose_name='Алиас')
    title = models.TextField(null=True, default='', verbose_name='Заголовок')
    txt = models.TextField(null=True, default='', verbose_name='Текст')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Пубикация')
```

---

Ну и немного доп. инфы:

---

По БД: реализовал метод "списки смежности" (owner ссылается на id той же сущности, что позволяет строить иерархию похожих объектов)

---

По цели: Сейчас пытаюсь вывести 3х-уровневую, разворачивающуюся менюшку, алгоритм сначала был описан на flask (вроде так пишется), затем перенесен на django (для меня было открытием в различии ginga-логики, но это все лирика). Вот, в преобразовании запроса с помощъю местной ORM случилась неведомая беда

---

Прошу помощи у более опытных/внимательных, за ранее всем спасибо, буду благодарен любой помощи

Comment: Почему вы не фильтруете Level2 во вьюхе сразу? Насколько я знаю, фильтрация в шаблоне невозможна таким образом, т.к. шаблон не поддерживает выполнение функций как, например jinja2.

Comment: и еще, нет смысла вызывать `all()`, чтобы потом вызвать `filter`. Вы можете написать `lvl2 = lavel.objects.filter(lvl=4)`. Сформируйте список, который вы хотите рендерить во вью и передайте в шаблон его уже готовым. Бизнес логика по идее не должна попадать в шаблон.

Comment: Я тоже думал по этому поводу... Но есть и свои проблемы

Comment: Посоветуйте, мне лучше сгенерировать html-код во въюхе, и передать его, или проще сформировать список/словарь самих объектов models, и передавать уже непосредственно его?

Comment: Вы зря огрызаетесь. @КонстантинКомиссаров дело говорит. Структуру данных нужно формировать во вьюхе, а не тащить хвосты сортировок и структурирования в шаблон. Вы делаете одну из частых ошибок новичков - смешиваете логику выполнения разных слоев MVC.

Comment: Впрочем, единственный вариант использования вызова сторонних функций в шаблонах - это кастомные теги и фильтры. Советую курить в эту сторону, если не придет осознание того, что гораздо проще собрать такую структуру данных во вьюхе.

Comment: @cauf , а где вы увидили что я огрызаюсь)
Я наоборот, сказал что так будет даже лучше, и стал рассуждать как лучше сформировать данные в самой въюхе)
Кстати, MVC в Django - MTV, так что тут путаница в терминологии, возможно по этому вы меня и не поняли.