# Пытаюсь собрать словарь из значений из БД

Tags: python-3.x, django, dict

Цель: Создать словарь, примерно такой структуры:

```
d = {
    0: {
        'id': 'test_id',
        'alias': 'test_alias',
        'l2': {
            'id': 'test2_id',
            'alias': 'test2_alias',
            'l3': {
                'id': 'test3_id',
                'alias': 'test3_alias'
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Подробнее: Потом нужно передать в html файл, где с его(словаря) помощью построить  трехуровневую разворачивающуюся менюшку (все началось с [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1210981/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d0%91%d0%94-sqlite) вопроса)

---

Что уже сделано:

```
for l1 in lavel.objects.all().filter(lvl=3):
    print(type(l1.id))
    d[l1.id]['id'] = l1.id
    d[l1.id]['alias'] = l1.alias
    d[l1.id]['l2'] = {}
    for l2 in lavel.objects.all().filter(lvl=4).filter(owner=l1.id):
        d[l1.id]['l2']['id'] = l2.id
        d[l1.id]['l2']['alias'] = l2.alias
        d[l1.id]['l2']['l3'] = {}
        for l3 in lavel.objects.all().filter(lvl=4).filter(owner=l1.id):
            d[l1.id]['l2']['l3']['id'] = l3.id
            d[l1.id]['l2']['l3']['alias'] = l3.alias
```

---

Структура БД (Если нужно):

```
class lavel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lvl = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0, verbose_name='Уровень')
    alias = models.TextField(null=True, default='', verbose_name='Алиас')
    title = models.TextField(null=True, default='', verbose_name='Заголовок')
    txt = models.TextField(null=True, default='', verbose_name='Текст')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Пубикация')
```

---

Ошибка: Не ясна. Ругается на строчку `d[l1.id]['id'] = l1.id`. Из `python3 manage.py shell` выводит такую ошибку:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-d483ce0c0e32> in <module>
      1 for l1 in lavel.objects.all().filter(lvl=3):
      2         print(type(l1.id))
----> 3         d[l1.id]['id'] = l1.id
      4         d[l1.id]['alias'] = l1.alias
      5         d[l1.id]['l2'] = {}

KeyError: 6
```

---

Помогите, пожалуйста, сформировать нормальный словарь... Честно, я уже 3й день на этом застрял, а в проекте еще куча работы... Я буду крайне признателен любым(!) наводкам и советам!!! За ранее спасибо!

Comment: Судя по ошибке `l1.id = 6`, а в словаре `d` ключа `6` видимо нет. Может надо его туда добавить? Разбирайтесь в вашей логике

Comment: Как добавить новый ключь? Я думал они динамически создаются....

Comment: Ну как: `d[l1.id] = dict()`, сами ключи создаются, если использовать `defaultdict`, но у вас там несколько уровней словаря и они разного типа. Надо пробовать.